# Does GetSelectedRangeS exist ? Excel OfficeJS API

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

GetSelectedRange() allows to get the current worksheet user selected range, but doesn't allow to have a multiple selection.

ie: selected A1:B3 and C4:D8

Does anybody know how to make it work ?

My purpose is to set a new range (with name : ie: myRange) with multiple user selected range.

Thanks

Comment: You can add them to an [`Union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union)  upon a [`Worksheet_SelectionChange()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa723501.aspx) event, though if I were you, I'd stray clear of `Select` altogether as it's pretty errir prone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beta version of Office.js now has a `Workbook.getSelectedRanges()` that returns a new `RangeAreas` object. We're working on the documentation now.

To use the new APIs, you must load the beta version of the library from https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js

To get intellisense, use https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.d.ts

You can also download a copy of the latter file. It has brief descriptions of the new APIs which is all we have until the docs are finished.

As always, we do not recommend using beta APIs in production add-ins.

UPDATE 2018/10/03:

We now have documentation for this feature: [Working with multiple ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-multiple-ranges?view=office-js)

Comment: When do you think you are going to release the API for production ?
Do you have the minimum Excel version it's working on ?

The versions 1803 and 1807 don't handle the API : error thrown : The API you are trying to use could not be found. It may be available in a newer version of Excel.

Comment: 1809 build 10820.20000 or later